# Laravel: fatalerrorexception - Call to undefined function link_to()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is probably a stupid error, but I'm new to Laravel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm working though a tutorial using Laravel 5, the tutorial is 4 for what it's worth and I'm adjusting the code. It's probably something simple, perhaps autoloading. It's as though Laravel 5 isn't importing the helper, perhaps as it is dev. More likely I'm being daft.

Error message: FatalErrorException in 7b6f3a7f0f4ee06975c6b0ad43b469a5 line 13: Call to undefined function link_to()

Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Task;

class TasksController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        // fetch all tasks
        $tasks = Task::all();

        // load a view to display them
        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));

    }
}
```

View:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>All Tasks</h1>

    @foreach($tasks as $task)
{{--        <li>{{ $task->title }}</li>--}}
        <li>{!! link_to('path', $task->title) !!}</li>

    @endforeach

</body>
</html>
```

Routes

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('tasks', 'TasksController@index');
```

Model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Task extends Eloquent
{

}
```

Comment: why do you have `{!!` and not `{{`?

Comment: That's because Laravel 5 escapes the values unlike Laravel 4. It's not the reason for the error though.

Comment: As a side note - using a Laravel 4 tutorial, while using Laravel 5 code is a *terrible* idea. Laravel 5 is not even in beta, and there a significant changes and ongoing issues between L4 and L5. Just learn Laravel 4 for now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `link_to` function. Use `url` instead:

```
{!! url('path', $task->title) !!}
```

Comment: There is but you need to install a package.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

```
<a href="{!! url('/auth/register') !!}">Register</a>
```

if you need parameters

```
<a href="{!! URL::to('users/'.$user->id.'/edit') !!}">Edit</a>
```